# Ember js - want to style outer route based on nested route

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, emblem.js

I am learning Ember, and I have an app that has nested routes.  The outer route renders an index of products that acts as a sidebar, and the inner route renders the selected product.

So I have a setup like this in my coffeescript router:

```
@resource 'products', ->
    @resource 'product'
```

And then I have a template like so for product_types.js.emblem:

```
each product in controller
    .product<NEED_SOMETHING_HERE>
```

I want NEED_SOMETHING_HERE to give me an extra attribute that will allow me to add a style to the product which will be rendered in the inner route.  A class "active", or something similar, is the convention I would use elsewhere.  What is the Ember way to do this?

Comment: This helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124201/ember-js-how-to-communicate-data-between-a-parent-routes-controller-and-a-chil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember actually does this automatically with the link-to helper!

Ember adds an "active" class when the link matches the current route

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_the-code-link-to-code-helper

Comment: when linking to external resources, please include the part relevant to the question